# Which is more common to say “I used to have a month off” or “I was used to having a month off” over Charismas holiday?

Tags: word-usage

There was the following sentence in Tina Fey’s “Tina Fey Bossy Pants”:

> " When I took the job at the front desk in early November, I had
>   stipulated that I had to have off a few days around Christmas because
>   I had already booked a flight home to see my family. This being my
>   first Christmas after college, **I was used to having a month off** over
>   the holidays, and cutting that down to a three-day weekend already had
>   me weepy and depressed." - ibid. P.69

I think I used to write “used to do”  when referring to habitual behavior.

Is there difference of nuance between “used to do” and “be used to doing”? If it’s exactly or almost same, which of “used to do” and “be used to doing” is used more often?

**P.S.**

As the second thought after posting this question, I came to think “be used to doing” is akin to “be accustomed to do / doing” and “be wont to do,” and structually different from “used to do,” but I’m not sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following:

**Be used to**:

Be used to + noun phrase or verb-ing (in this pattern used is an adjective and to is a preposition).

-I am used to getting up early in the morning. I don't mind it.

-He didn't complain about the noise nextdoor - he was used to it.

-If you are used to something, you have often done or experienced it, so it's not    strange, new or difficult for you.

The opposite of be used to is be not used to.
I am not used to the new system yet.

**Get used to**

Get used to + noun phrase or verb-ing (in this pattern used is an adjective and to is a preposition).

-I got used to getting up early in the morning.

-After a while he didn't mind the noise in the office - he got used to it.

If you get used to something, you become accustomed to it. 
It is the process of becoming used to something.

**Used to:**

Used to + verb refers to a habit or state in the past. It is used only in the past simple.
Past habits

-If you used to do something, you did it for a period of time in the past, but you don't do it any more.

-We used to live there when I was a child.

-I used to walk to work every day when I was younger.
Past states:

It is also used  to express a state that existed in the past but doesn't exist now. They are expressed using stative verbs such as have, believe, know and like.

Answer (score 3):

*Use to* is describing past 'actions'. *Was used to __* means had become accustomed to __*. They are not exactly the same.

> I *used to cry* every time I saw that movie.
>   I *used to get* muscle cramps in my legs after running.

It's not really a habit. It's just something that happened with regularity. It *could* be used with a habit: *I used to bite my nails...*

> I *was used to using maps* to find my way around; once I got a GPS, I couldn't believe how much easier traveling became. Now that I'm used to my GPS, I can't use a map come hell or high water.

This means *accustomed to*.

As they are not synonymous, I can't say which one is used more often. It depends on what you're trying to say.